# Where can I see my teams

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, old-teams

Where can I see a list of the teams I've joined? Not sure if that is really a problem, but someone being in a lot of team might not remember the name of them all.

There will probably be a lot of teams, so a quick way of going to our team's page might be great.

Comment: Look at your profile - on the left - under "Teams"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is already available at your profile. Please, see the picture below:

[image: profile]